# Ubuntu Openstack AutoPilot Networking Issues

Tags: juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

I have a really weird networking issue I can't seem to figure out. Here's what I am using to build my Openstack Cloud

- MAAS 1.7
- Ubuntu Openstack Auto Pilot multi node installation method with 8 nodes.
- Corporate network 172.20.8.0/22 (Using this as Public CIDR)
- MAAS DHCP/DNS network 192.168.0.0/16 (this space uses 172.20.8.x address to go out to the internet as public address)

I can get everything installed and I am using public network floating IP range 172.20.9.110 - 172.20.9.120

I see 172.20.9.110 assigned to openvswitch and can ping it

but when I create an instance, I cannot ping/reach that instance on 172.20.9.111.

Also, I know autopilot uses 10.10.0.0/16 as internal address space and this might be a problem, since we do have 10.10.0.0/24 in use.

Two questions, where can I start looking to troubleshoot and is there a way I can modify the address space GRE tunnels use in AutoPilot

Thanks